# Setting marshalTo in MarshallingMessageConverter in XML configuration getting Invalid property 'marshalTo'

Tags: java, spring-jms

I'm trying to create a MarshallingMessageConverter, here is my XML:

```
<bean id="marshallingMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="marshalTo" value="MARSHAL_TO_TEXT_MESSAGE" />
</bean>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error setting property values; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: 
Invalid property 'marshalTo' of bean class
[org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter]: 
Bean property 'marshalTo' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. 
Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Is this because MarshallingMessageConverter doesn't have a *getMarshalTo* method, and so setting it in this way isn't working?

It looks like it should be possible, as I found https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-614, and someone else said they have the following config working:

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller"/>
<bean id="xstream" class="org.springframework.oxm.support.MarshallingMessageConverter"
  p:marshaller-ref="marshaller" p:unmarshaller-ref="marshaller" p:marshalTo="2"/>
<!--marshalTo=2 sets the marshaller to text message rather than bytes message-->
```

So I feel like maybe it's something I'm missing. I've tried using an int in the value, but that doesn't work either.

I want to use XML config because I'm using Spring Integration, and don't want to be pulling beans out of the app-context using Java.

I am using Spring version 3.2.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing something... I was looking at the documentation for

```
org.springframework.oxm.support.MarshallingMessageConverter
```

but the one that I was using was

```
org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter
```

which has  the method, toTargetType().

Not sure if I should delete my question or leave it here in case someone else does the same thing.